# Is it possible in Pyspark to get the csv representation of a dataframe as a string?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to get the same result as a pandas [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) called without a path argument. Currently I'm saving the dataframe as a csv to then read it and I'd like to avoid this step.

> path_or_buf: str or file handle, default None
> File path or object, **if None is provided the result is returned as a string**. If a non-binary file object is passed, it should be opened with newline=’’, disabling universal newlines. If a binary file object is passed, mode might need to contain a ‘b’.

Having a big dataset, the [toPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html) function doesn't work.
Does someone know if it's possible in pyspark or know a work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_csv`:

```
csv_string = df.agg(F.concat_ws('\n', F.collect_list(F.to_csv(F.struct(df.columns))))).head()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `to_csv` to convert list of columns to csv as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.select(f.to_csv(f.struct(df.columns))).show(truncate=False)
```